# How to ignore spark_home when unit testing with pyspark

Tags: pyspark, pytest

I trying to write unit-tests with pyspark. Tests pass with the following configuration when `SPARK_HOME` is NOT set. There are multiple installations of spark on our machines and if `SPARK_HOME` is set to one of them tests fails on that machine.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark_session(request):
    session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .master("local[2]")\
        .appName("pytest-pyspark-local-testing")\
        .getOrCreate()

    request.addfinalizer(lambda: session.stop())
    quiet_py4j()
    return session
```

I have tried `os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = ""` which gets `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './bin/spark-submit': './bin/spark-submit` error.

I have also tried `os.unsetenv('SPARK_HOME')` which gets `Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number`. When I don't try to unset the env var, I get this same error as well.

How can I make sure that my tests will work on any machine simply ignoring any environment variables.

Comment: What about clearing the env var? `os.unsetenv('SPARK_HOME')`

Comment: @hoefling still not working. Question updated.